# Is it possible to push updated to multiple config versions using trigger.io reload?

Tags: trigger.io

Trigger.io reload allows you to push updates to a specific config version. Can I push the changes (assuming my JS is backwards compatible) to multiple config versions - so "Push Stream" using config A, then change to config B and do push stream again?

It is a pretty common use case, as users have different versions of the app, and hence different config versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the "reload" page in the Trigger Toolkit you should see an option to "Show other built configs"

If you click it you will have the option to "Restore config" for any of your builds and any "Push to stream" operations you do will then be directed to that build config.

A good development workflow is to maintain a branch for each build configuration to make it easier to recall the state of what you've shipped.